# Need to cover code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

Hi Below are my class and testclass.
please check and help me out.

### class:

```
public class IntegrationExecution{

  public Boolean IsOrgName {set; get;}

  public IntegrationExecution(String ClassOrgName){  
  if(!Test.isRunningTest()){    

  {  
  IsOrgName = true;  
  }       
  else{  
  IsOrgName = false;  
  }  
  }  
   else{  
IsOrgName = true;  
  }

  }  
  public Boolean getIsOrgName(){  
      return IsOrgName;  
  }  
}
```

### test class:

```
@isTest         
public class IntegrationExecutionTest{           
    Static testMethod void Integration1 (){        
IntegrationExecution int_cls = new IntegrationExecution(Label.Name);     

IntegrationExecution int_cls1 = new IntegrationExecution('re');
        int_cls1.getIsOrgName();   
           }   
}
```

below is uncovered lines
[image]

Comment: Venkatesh, please provide what you already have covered or any specific areas you're having difficulty covering. The Developer Console is very useful in identifying areas that can still be covered - there are many resources on how to use it if you do a web search.

Comment: I added the uncovered lines please check once Brain

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this line here will prevent you from hitting the other lines:

```
if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
```

Try removing that from your code then your test class should hit at least one of the conditions, you will need to create both conditions with your test data.

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is assigning IsOrgName with boolean values based on conditions and then assertion statements to check if the IsOrgName is setting to true or false.

Comment: I have shanred the screenshot.please check it and let me know Giene.

Comment: From the screen shot it clearly states that both the conditions are not tested/asserted. Hence you need to put in the assertion statements to validate the condition where IsOrgName is getting set to true and false. that should give you enough coverage.

Comment: Was your issue resolved?